# When to Stop Rolling and Bail

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Consider the following game.

> P has a fair $6$ sided die and continuously rolls it while keeping
>   track of the sum, $S$, of the top faces. P can bail anytime and leave
>   with $S$ number of dollars. However, if $S$ is ever a perfect square,
>   the game ends and $P$ gets nothing.

When is it most profitable for $P$ to quit? What is the expected amount of money does $P$ make when $P$ quits at this optimal time?

I ran sum simulations of this and found that on average, the game runs for $8$ rolls and the expected earnings of $P$ is around $28$ dollars. Can we prove this?

The distribution of earnings with $8$ rolls is shown below.
[image]

Comment: You'll want to quit **only** if you can "hit" a square. But as you (after a while) have the same probability to hit each square, and that the square are further and further away, I think there is no optimal time to quit.

Comment: What's up with fractional earnings?

Comment: You should not decide in advance how many rolls to attempt.  Instead you should decide to quit when the sum hits particular values.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977679/toss-a-fair-die-until-the-cumulative-sum-is-a-perfect-square-expected-value and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176195/would-you-ever-stop-rolling-the-die