# stop rolling dice until the cumulated sum is perfect square

Tags: probability

> You have a six-sided dice, and you will receive money that equals to sum of all the numbers you roll. After each roll, if the sum is a perfect square, the game ends and you lose all the money. If not, you can decide to keep rolling or stop the game. If your sum is 35 now, should you keep play?

The iteration is very simply:
$$f(N) = \max(N, \dfrac{1}{6}\Big(f(N+1)+\cdots+f(N+6)\Big)).$$
The only condition is that $f(n)=0$ if $n$ is perfect square. I saw the same question here:

[Toss a fair die until the cumulative sum is a perfect square-Expected Value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977679/toss-a-fair-die-until-the-cumulative-sum-is-a-perfect-square-expected-value)

> The only time we might consider stopping is when $k$ is nearly a perfect square. Suppose $k \approx n^2$ (more specifically, take $n^2-6\leq k<n^2$).

> If we stop, our score is always at least $n^2-6$. If we try to continue past $n^2$, and then stop when we nearly reach $(n+1)^2$, the probability that we actually make it past $n^2$ is at most $\frac{5}{6}$, so the expected score is at best $\frac{5}{6}\left((n+1)^2 - 1\right)=\frac{5}{6}\left(n^2+2n\right)$. So stopping now is better than going through $(n+1)^2$ whenever $n^2-6>\frac{5}{6}(n^2+2n)$, and possibly sooner. This inequality holds whenever $n \geq 13$.

I think the continue value can be larger than $(n+1)^2-1.$

Comment: The continue value is indeed larger than $(n+1)^2-1$ for small $n$.  But not for large $n$.  One way of looking at it is to see that you have to pass each square number and the probability of that is about $\left(\frac56\right)^n$ (not exactly, as you might pass $1^2$ and $2^2$ in a single jump) while the amount you have and may lose is about $n^2$, with the power falling faster than the square increases.  So there will be somewhere where it is too risky to continue and your quote illustrates how to put a bound on this.  Then you would take the stop value, and that will not exceed $(n+1)^2-1$

Comment: @Henry agree with you for the large $n.$ However how to compute e.g. 35 in this question. From the original answer, it seems we can only use simulation for the specific $n.$

Comment: Once you have an upper bound (in the linked answer, stop when at any of $163,164,165,166,167,168$ as it is not worth the risk of continuing) you can then calculate each of the smaller values by recursion rather than simulation